# Razor attributes on Text Field vs Password Field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5.

**Text Field (notice the htmlAttributes):**

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddr, 
  new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

**Password Field (notice lack of htmlAttributes):**

```
@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Passwd, new {@class = "form-control"})
```

This is the only way I can make it work.

On the Text Field, if I take away the `htmlAttributes` it does not work.

On the Password field, if I add `htmlAttributes`, it does not work.

**Why???**

Comment: You can't pass in `htmlAttributes` to `EditorFor()` prior to MVC 5.1 but you can write a custom template or use `TextBoxFor` instead.

Comment: HTML-helpers are static classes with static methods, and like any call to a static method you need to give it the correct arguments; I think you can add `null` instead of `new htmlAttributes` if you don't want them. If you really need the html attributes on the PasswordFor, please concider writing custom HTML helpers.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that difference lies in these methods signatures. 
`PasswordFor` has the following signature:

`MvcHtmlString Html.PasswordFor(Expression<Func<dynamic,TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes)`

where the second argument is an object which represents `htmlAttributes`. So, in this case you are just creating this `htmlAttributes` object using constructor syntax and passing it as a parameter.

However, `EditorFor` is a little bit different:

`EditorExtensions.EditorFor<TModel, TValue> Method (HtmlHelper<TModel>, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>, Object)`

where the second argument is an object that contains additionalViewData. As far as I know, `htmlAttributes` can be a property of this object. So, in this case you are using object initializer syntax for object creation, where you set `htmlAttributes` property with the value of `new { @class = "form-control" }`.

Answer (score 1):

**PasswordFor:**

The `Html.PasswordFor()` method generates a input password element with specified name, value and html attributes.
   Signature example :

```
 public static MvcHtmlString PasswordFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes);
```

**EditorFor:**

This control is bit smart. It renders HTML markup based on the datatype of the property.you can pass in an anonymous object whose properties would somehow get added as attributes on some tag, especially for the built-in editor templates. You would need to write your own custom editor template and pass the value you want as additional viewdata.

Signature example :

```
public static MvcHtmlString EditorFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object additionalViewData);
```